# Do I create a separate class for collection or store them in the same class?

Tags: java, oop

I have 3 classes, **`Team`**, **`Game`** and **`Round`**.

**`Game`** contains a list of **`Teams`**.

**`Round`** contains a list of **`Game`**.

I'm going to create multiple objects from each class.

Should I create another classes for this like which contain a list of each object:

```
GameRepository
TeamRepository
RoundRepository
```

Or should I just keep the collections in their own classes?

Comment: Java offers a lot of Collections. Use them as is.

Comment: So I should keep a list of games in the class Game for example?

Comment: @sander Consider it from the business logic point of view. Do you have `Game` as an entity? Then yes. Do you just happen to have lists of `Team`s once in a while? Then probably no.

Comment: I guess it should be:  Game contains a list of Teams. AND Game contains a list of Rounds.

Comment: What would you use the repositories for? It all depends on what you want to achieve with all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember [the single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

I am sure your classes already have a plenty of methods to manage/control the inner state. Do they need another responsibility to take? **No, they don't.**

Storing items, being a collection is a completely new responsibility and it shouldn't be messed up with the already-given ones.

---

On the other hand, there is nothing wrong if a `Round` will contain a `List<Game>` and a `Game` will have references to `Team`s. But you need to be sure that, for example, removing a `Game` wouldn't affect `Team` instances. The issue is still to decide which class keeps instances, and which one just refers them.

Comment: So going with the repository would be better and cleaner code I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If I have to do that, I would do it this way(These classes can be in different files):

```
public class Game{
List<Team>teamList;
}

public class Round{
 List<Game>gameList;
}

public class Team{

}
```

That way if you have an instance of a Round, you have everything you need

Comment: Isn't this just repeating what the OP was asking?